# Make /usr/bin/security ask for Touch ID verification

Tags: macos, command-line, security, keychain, touch-id

I can add a password to the keyring like this:

```
security add-generic-password -a $USER -s my-password-entry -T /usr/bin/security -U -w
```

... and read it like this:

```
security find-generic-password -a $USER -s my-password-entry -g -w
```

But is there a way to make `security` ask for Touch ID verification every time I ask for `my-password-entry`?

References:

- [accessing Keychain Access from terminal - OSX](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/170431/5723)
- http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/security/osx-10.5.php

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can modify your command line to look like this when adding the password:

```
security add-generic-password -a $USER -s my-password-entry -T "" -U -w
```

This will ensure that no application is trusted to access the data without warning.

Comment: This makes it ask for my password, not fingerprint / Touch ID.

Comment: Hmm, odd - doesn't it allow you to either touch id or password? - Have you tried giving it the password the first time, and then try again and see if it will allow Touch ID? (usually touch id is not allowed just after a reboot for example)

Comment: Are you using a MacBook Pro?

Comment: I'm using a Macbook Pro 16".  It will ask for password every time, until I select "Always allow".  Then it won't ask for anything anymore.  I want it to ask for Touch ID every time..

Comment: Are you on Catalina? - I'm on Mojave, maybe that makes a difference.

Comment: Yup, I'm on Catalina